# Trying to break out of fgets while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings, fgets, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char c[20], result[50];
    int bool = 0, count = 0, i;
    
    while(fgets(c,20,stdin) != NULL){
        int stringSize = strlen(c);
        if(stringSize == 11){
            
            int ascii = (int)(c[i]);
            
            for(i = 0; i < stringSize; i++){
            
                if(ascii >= 'A' && ascii <= 'Z'){
                    bool = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        if(bool == 1){
            count++;
            strcat(result,c);
        }
    
    printf("%d", count);
    printf("%s",result);
}
```

Good morning, I am fairly new to programming, and I've spent quite a while Googling and searching around for this issue already, but I can't seem to wrap my head about it.
Basically I'm trying to filter an fgets so that it reads each string, and if they're capital letters, they're "valid". However, I can't even get the fgets to stop accepting more input.

Edit: The idea is to store in result every String that has 10 capital letters, and for the fgets while loop to break once the user gives no input ('\0')

Comment: Have you tried entering Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows)? Or is the idea to accept one input string when it complies?

Comment: `int ascii = (int)(c[i]);` uses `i` uninitialized. It looks like this statement should be in the loop, not before.

Comment: If the idea is to accept just one string if it is all uppercase, you need to reset the flag at the start of each `fgets` loop (not outside the loop). Then if any character isn't upper case, set the flag. But the problem statement isn't clear - please show an example input and required output.

Comment: I've edited with the intentions, my bad, should have been more clear. I basically want it to run for as long as there is an input, and for result to only store strings with 10 capital letters.

Comment: There will be "no input" when `c[0] == '\n'` since `fgets` retains the newline (if room). So the test can be simplified to `if(c[0] == '\n') break;` But you can't "store every string in `result`" because that is a single string, not an array of strings. Aside: `int ascii = (int)(c[i]);` is in the wrong place, it should be inside the next loop, as mentioned by mch.

Comment: A console doesn't know about `EOF`, which would be the signal for `fgets` to return the null pointer (after all other text has been evaluated). So you either need to simulate (see @WeatherVane 's initial comment) or implement a special command for terminating the loop, e.g. if input equals *'exit'* or *'quit'* – or is empty – you explicitly leave the loop (`break`).

Comment: @JulianFahr Again its is unclear whether the target string shall contain only 10 characters that are upper case letters or any number of characters among them there are 10 upper case letters.

Comment: The indentation is very confusing. Please fix it.

Comment: So please show a few *examples* of entered strings, and what is accepted as input.

Comment: How many valid inputs do you expect? `strcat` could place at most 4 results (after concatenating the forty characters there's no room for the terminating null character to concatenate another string of length 10). In any case you should abort concatenating after the maximum of storable input strings has been reached!

Comment: Not related to the problem, but this is a bad idea: `int bool = 0`. There is a type `bool` in `stdbool.h` As soon as you need this for other purposes, your code will break. You should not use identifiers that are defined by C standard even if you don't yet include the related headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are entering strings from the standard input stream then it is better to rewrite the condition of the while loop the following way

```
while( fgets(c,20,stdin) != NULL && c[0] != '\n' ){
```

In this case if the user just pressed the Enter key without entering a string then the loop stops its iterations.

Pay attention to that fgets can append the new line character '\n' to the entered string. You should remove it like

```
c[ strcspn( c, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Then you could write

```
size_t n = strlen( c );

if ( n == 10 )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i != n && 'A' <= c[i] && c[i] <= 'Z' ) ++i;

    bool = i == 10;
}
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use the name `bool` because such a name is introduced as a macro in the header `<stdbool.h>`.

Also it seems this if statement

```
    if(bool == 1){
        count++;
        strcat(result,c);
    }
```

must be within the while loop. And the array result must be initially initialized

```
char c[20], result[50] = { '\0' };
```

Comment: Nice... I'd assume `char* nl = strchr(...); if(nl) { *nl = 0; }` to be more efficient, though.